# Solving $X'(x)=X(x)M(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am aware of how to solve a system $x'=Ax$ for an $n$-vector $x$ and $n\times n$ matrix M and the necessary generalization for matrices. If $X \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ is a matrix, forming $X'(x) = M(x)X(x)$.

**Question:** How would I go about solving a system of the form $X'(x) = X(x) M(x)$?

**Edit:** An equation $X(x) = C(e^{\int M(x) dx})^{-1}$ will not suffice as $X'(x)\neq -X'(x) M(x)$ due to lack of commutativity.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem and is very common in high energy physics. You'll want to look up the term "(time) ordered exponential". Your ordering is a bit different than the usual, but you might be able to rescue it via transposes.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, I made an edit to my question given your advice. Do you think that I missed something with my idea? Thanks again

Comment: Oldie but goodie: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/19ways+.pdf

Comment: @copper.hat, do you think that its section on Lagrange Sylvester interpolation could give me a closed form solution for the matrix exponential?

Comment: I doubt it for a time varying (or whatever $x$ is) system. Purely as an aside, in linear control systems, the solution to the system starting from $I$ at time $t_0$ is referred to as the state transition matrix and denoted by $\Phi(t,t_0)$.

Comment: Define $\mu(x)=\exp(-\int_0^x M(s)\,{\rm d}s)$. What makes you think $\mu'(x)=-\mu(x)M(x)$? This is in general not true, because $M(s_1)$ and $M(s_2)$ may fail to commute when $s_1\ne s_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an explicit series formula for the solution generalizing the exponential series for the case where $M$ is constant. Once you have the right formula it is quite easy to check it works, but how to get the right formula in the first place? Let's start by writing
$$ X(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n(x). $$
where $X_n(x)$ are to be determined.
You didn't specify an initial condition, but a natural one is $X(0)=I$, the identity matrix (the solutions for other initial conditions can be easily obtained from the solution for this, one by the way). A simple way to make the initial condition hold from our Ansatz is to take
\begin{align*}
X_0 \equiv I && \text{ and } && 0 = X_1(0) = X_2(0) = X_3(0) = \ldots ,
\end{align*}
so let's go ahead and do that that. Plugging our Ansatz into
$$X'(x) = X(x)M(x)$$
and assuming it makes sense to differentiate term-by-term, we then get
$$ X_1'(x) + X_2'(x) + X_3'(x) \ldots = M(x) + X_1(x)M(x) + X_2(X)M(x) + \ldots.$$
A rather cheap way to make sure this equality holds is to match up terms on the left and right, i.e. require
\begin{align*}
X_1'(x) =  M(x) && X_2'(x) = X_1(x)M(x) && X_3'(x) = X_2(x)M(x) && \ldots
\end{align*}
This gives us a not particularly difficult recurrence relation to solve. Integrating (remember we put $X_n(0)=0$ for $n>0$), we get
\begin{align*}
X_1(x) &= \int_0^x M(x_1) \ dx_1 \\
X_2(x) &= \int_0^x X_1(x_2)M(x_2) \ dx_2 = \int_0^x \int_0^{x_2} M(x_1) M(x_2) \ dx_1 \ dx_2 
\end{align*}
and so on. The general term is:
$$ X_n(x) = \int\cdots\int_{0 \leq x_1 \leq \ldots \leq x_n \leq x} M(x_1) M(x_2) \cdots M(x_n) \ d x_1 \cdots d x_n.$$
Well OK, that's a bit imprecise. What does this mean when $x <0$? This is not a very serious issue, however, and can be completely eliminated by a simple change of variables.

Once we have the right formula, it's not all that difficult to do the analysis necessary to show that $X(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty X(x)$ indeed solves the IVP. One piece of relevant information is that the Euclidean volume of the $n$-simplex  $0 \leq x_1 \ldots \leq x_n \leq x$ is $x^n/n!$ as follows from noting that this simplex is, up to measure zero, a fundamental domain for the action of the symmetric group of order $n$ on the cube $[0,x]^n$  which permutes coordinates. This gives you estimates like
$$\|X_n(x)\| \leq \frac{|x|^n}{n!} \sup_{0 \leq y \leq x} \|M(y)\|^n$$
which allow you, for $x$ confined to any fixed bounded interval, to dominate the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n(x)$ by an exponential series.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer, @Mike F. Do you think the argument with right multiplication would still be valid? Does the proposal $X(x) = C(e^{\int M(x) dx})^{-1}$ neglect something important about the system? I had not previously considered that such a recurrence relation was possible, but I've now learned! It reminds me of a practice Putnam problem that my friend showed me. Could your series solution be represented as a Neumann series if the integrals were treated like operators? Thank you for your insight, I will continue to study your response for the next few days!

Comment: @JPwin The problem with your solution is that you have wrongly assumed the 1D chain rule for exponentials still applies with your matrix-valued integrating factor. The derivative of $e^{N(x)}$ is not $e^{N(x)}N'(x)$ in general!

Comment: Also it's worth noting the series given in this answer can be found by applying the definite integral $\int_0^x$ to the original differential equation and then using recursion (with the optimistic assumption of convergence, of course).

Comment: Thank you, I remember that I was unable to find a derivative property for the matrix exponential, so I assumed what I thought would make it easiest. Thank you again for the clarification.